# Does a CDHP plan count as an HDHP plan?

Tags: united-states, taxes, health-insurance, hsa, hdhp

I have a CDHP health insurance plan that comes with an Health Savings Account. As I'm filing my taxes, Turbotax has informed me that my HSA is being additionally taxed because I do not have HDHP coverage.

Does my CDHP plan count as HDHP for tax purposes? If not, why do employers offer CDHP with HSA?

If its relevant: my deductible is $2000 in network and $4000 out of network

I found [this](https://www.zanebenefits.com/blog/health-savings-account-hsa-2016-rules-requirements) site which claims that the 2016 minimum deductible for HSAs is $1300 for my case, which seems to imply that my plan *is* an HDHP. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Are you by any chance claimed as a dependent on someone else's tax return?  Do you have any other health coverage that might make you no longer eligible for the HSA?

Comment: Do you have any more information as to why Turbotax thinks you don't have HDHP coverage?

Comment: @BenMiller I am not a dependent and I have no other insurance

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why TurboTax thinks you don't have HDHP coverage.  Did TurboTax ask you if you had an HDHP, and you said "no"?

Comment: @BenMiller Yeah, I initially said no because my plan said CDHP and not HDHP, but it seems like that was a mistake.

Comment: I understand.  Yes, if the HSA is included as part of the CDHP, it really must be an HSA-eligible HDHP.  You can ask your insurance company explicitly if there is any doubt.

Comment: Did you know with certainty that the account is an HSA? If it is there will be money in box 12 of your W-2 with a code of W. That number should equal the amount you contributed plus the amount the company contributed to the HSA.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, Consumer-Driven (or Consumer-Directed) Health Plan is a relatively recent marketing term for health insurance plans.  The term has no legal definition, but a CDHP generally is a lower-cost health plan bundled with some sort of health spending plan, such as an HSA, FSA, or HRA.

A CDHP *can* consist of an HSA and an HSA-eligible HDHP, but it also can be something else.

There are several regulations that a health plan needs to meet in order to be considered an HSA-eligible HDHP, and the best way to determine whether or not it is would be to ask the insurance company themselves.  If your plan is a CDHP with an included HSA, and your deductible is over $1300 (for a self-only plan), it is most likely an HSA-eligible HDHP.

Remember that in order to remain [qualified for the HSA](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p969/ar02.html#en_US_2015_publink1000204025), you aren't allowed to have any other health coverage.